# RuboCop offenses are not highlighted in VSCodium when project is loaded from workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubocop, vscodium, ruby-lsp

I use [Ruby LSP](https://github.com/Shopify/ruby-lsp) to lint Ruby code with RuboCop in VSCodium.

When I open the editor either from the console:

```bash
$ codium .
```

or from the command dialog (alt + F2), any offenses found are properly highlighted:

[image: RuboCop highlights offenses]

However, when I load that same project after switching workspaces (with [vscode-workspace-switcher](https://github.com/sadesyllas/vscode-workspace-switcher) extension), nothing is highlighted:

[image: RuboCop does not highlight offenses]

It's like some kind of context is missing when the workspace is loaded.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, although I'm not sure why a configuration works and the other one does not.

As I said, I'm using the extension [vscode-workspace-switcher](https://github.com/sadesyllas/vscode-workspace-switcher) to switch between different workspaces in VSCodium.

The `code-workspace` file for my project was something like following:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "../<path/to/my/project>"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

Notice path is a relative path to where the project is placed.

However, by chance I realized that when RuboCop offenses were properly displayed in the editor, the path to those files were something like `/media/david/<path/to/the/file>`.

So I changed the configuration in the `code-workspace` file as follows:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "/media/david/<path/to/my/project>"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

I went back to the project and now RuboCop offenses are properly displayed in the editor.

By the way, it doesn't work with `~/<path/to/my/project>` nor `/home/david/<path/to/my/project>`.